# Additional data not being passed with JQuery POST request

Tags: jquery

I have a html page sends a CGI request (hosted via IIS server).

This works perfectly.

**HTML Page**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js">  
</script>
<script src="sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="slam" action= "http://localhost/Dev/SIAS/slam/siscgi.exe" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="B1">        
    <input type="hidden" name="request" value="sample">
    <input type="hidden" name="format" value="xml">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**sample.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var siscgi = $("#slam").attr('action');


$("#B1").click(function (evt) {
    var data= $("#slam").serialize();
    $.post(siscgi,data,
            function(data,status){          

    });  
});

});
```

I am trying to remove the hidden input fields and instead pass them directly as additional data in the javascript like this:

**sample.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var siscgi = $("#slam").attr('action');


$("#B1").click(function (evt) {
    var data= {request : "sample", format : "xml"};
    $.post(siscgi,data,
            function(data,status){          

    });  
});

});
```

This fails, as the server (via siscgi.exe) sends an error saying missing parameters - request and format params are not being sent.

The result is a xml tree that needs to be displayed in the browser.

Can anyone let me know, how to fix this issue?

Comment: This looks good to me. jQuery should take care of serializing the data correctly. Have a look at your browser's developer tools and see which data is really sent. Note that the second example doesn't send `submit=B1`, which could be a problem.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think the first will sent it either - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WE94U/1/

Comment: When B1's click event is triggered, POST request is sent. So why do we need to send Submit??

Comment: I receive a response, when I employ the first method (serialized hidden inputs). But server sends a missing param error with the second method(no hidden fields and POST has manual data)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look properly at the code apparently. I thought the submit button had a `name` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is still a submit button in a form, so its default action causes it to be submitted, and the page is replaced before your ajax post gets a reply. It only seemed to be working in the first case because there was no difference between the data you submitted with ajax and the data that was submitted by the default action. You were actually submitting the form twice every time, which you should be able to prove by examining the server log.

In the second version, you're still sending 2 requests, and the one whose response you see is the one without the required fields.

`evt.preventDefault()` should fix it.